# Energy-momentum tensor of Bosonic Ghost Action in String Theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, action, ghosts

When quantizing bosonic string theory by means of the path integral, one inverts the Faddeev-Popov determinant by going to [Grassmann variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_variable), yielding:
$$
S_{\mathrm{ghosts}} = \frac{-i}{2\pi}\int\sqrt{\hat{g}}b_{\alpha\beta}\hat{\nabla^{\alpha}}c^{\beta}d^2\tau,
$$
where the $-i/2\pi$ just comes from convention/Wick rotated or not. My first problem is the notion of the 'fudicial' metric $\hat{g}$. I find its role in the path integral procedure a bit confusing. What is its relation to the 'normal' metric $g$? Why is it introduced? Related to this confusion is that fact in my lecture notes it is said that the energy momentum tensor is given by:
$$
T_{\alpha\beta} :=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{\hat{g}}}\frac{\delta S_g}{\delta\hat{g}^{\alpha\beta}} = \frac{i}{4\pi}\left( b_{\alpha\gamma}\hat{\nabla}_{\beta}c^{\gamma} + b_{\beta\gamma}\hat{\nabla}_{\alpha}c^{\gamma} - c^{\gamma}\nabla_{\gamma}b_{\alpha\beta} - g_{\alpha\beta}b_{\gamma\delta}\nabla^{\gamma}c^{\delta} \right),
$$
I have trouble deriving this. Varying the $\sqrt{\hat{g}}$ in the action yields the last term I would say:
$$
\delta\sqrt{\hat{g}} = -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\hat{g}}\hat{g}_{\alpha\beta}\delta \hat{g}^{\alpha\beta}
$$
 However, this term does not have a 'hat' on the covariant derivative, which I find strange. The first and second term follow easily when writing the action with all indices low (except for a factor of 1/2), but I really don't see where the third term comes from and it also misses a hat on the covariant derivative. It looks like there has been done a partial integration, but I don't see why. I guess I am missing the point of the fiducial metric here. Explanation greatly appreciated!

EDIT: In the discussion below I mentioned that $b_{\alpha\beta}$ is traceless: $b_{\alpha\beta}g^{\alpha\beta} = 0$, I forgot to place that here. It is a consequence of the path integral procedure.

Comment: I've been meaning to do this for quite a long time. I've decided to work it out now. Will put up my answer once I'm done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's part of my answer to the derivation of the EM tensor for the ghost action. It does not match the expression you gave, but I may have made a mistake. Can you check my work?

We start with the action
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
S_{gh} &= - \frac{i}{2\pi} \int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{g} g^{\alpha\mu} b_{\alpha\beta} \nabla_\mu c^\beta \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Let us now vary the action w.r.t. metric. We get
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\delta S_{gh} &= - \frac{i}{2\pi} \int d^2 \sigma \left( \delta \sqrt{g} \right) g^{\alpha\mu} b_{\alpha\beta} \nabla_\mu c^\beta  \\
&~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~- \frac{i}{2\pi} \int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{g} \left( \delta g^{\alpha\mu} \right) b_{\alpha\beta} \nabla_\mu c^\beta  \\
&~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~- \frac{i}{2\pi} \int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{g} g^{\alpha\mu} b_{\alpha\beta} \delta \left( \nabla_\mu c^\beta \right) \\
&= - \frac{i}{4\pi} \int d^2 \sigma  \sqrt{g} \left[ b_{\alpha\mu} \nabla_\beta c^\mu + b_{\beta\mu} \nabla_\alpha c^\mu   - g_{\alpha\beta}   b_{\rho\sigma} \nabla^\rho c^\sigma \right]  \delta  g^{\alpha\beta}   \\
&~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ - \frac{i}{2\pi} \int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{g} g^{\alpha\mu} b_{\alpha\beta} c^\lambda    \delta \Gamma^\beta_{\mu\lambda} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
We now use
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\delta \Gamma^\beta_{\mu\lambda} = \frac{1}{2} g^{\beta\rho} \left[ \nabla_\lambda \delta g_{\rho \mu} + \nabla_\mu \delta g_{\rho \lambda} - \nabla_\rho \delta g_{\mu\lambda}\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Note that in particular, it is a tensor. The last term then becomes
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
I &=   - \frac{i}{2\pi} \int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{g} g^{\alpha\mu} b_{\alpha\beta} c^\lambda    \delta \Gamma^\beta_{\mu\lambda}  \\
&=   - \frac{i}{4\pi} \int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{g}  b^{\mu\rho} c^\lambda \left[ \nabla_\lambda \delta g_{\rho \mu} + \nabla_\mu \delta g_{\rho \lambda} - \nabla_\rho \delta g_{\mu\lambda}\right]\\
&=   - \frac{i}{4\pi} \int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{g}  b^{\mu\rho} c^\lambda   \nabla_\lambda \delta g_{\rho \mu}  \\
&= - \frac{i}{4\pi} \int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{g}     \nabla_\lambda \left( b_{\alpha\beta} c^\lambda \right)  \delta g^{\alpha\beta} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
We then have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\delta S_{gh}  &= - \frac{i}{4\pi} \int d^2 \sigma  \sqrt{g} \left[ b_{\alpha\mu} \nabla_\beta c^\mu + b_{\beta\mu} \nabla_\alpha c^\mu   - g_{\alpha\beta}   b_{\rho\sigma} \nabla^\rho c^\sigma +   \nabla_\lambda \left( b_{\alpha\beta} c^\lambda \right)  \right]  \delta  g^{\alpha\beta}  
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: I am pretty sure that my expression for the energy-momentum tensor is correct, I have found it on page 50 of Lust and Theisen's Lectures on String Theory. I think the first two terms in your expression are correct, but the third and fourth are not..

Comment: THe third term is also correct? I thought it matches what you have. I am worried about the last term though.

Comment: maybe we can use the fact that $\beta_{\alpha\beta}$ is traceless?

Comment: @Erik There is a sign error in the last integration by parts, so you get in fact: $- \nabla_\lambda \left( b_{\alpha\beta} c^\lambda \right) \delta g^{\alpha\beta}$. Assuming a flat frame give $- c^\lambda \partial_\lambda ( b_{\alpha\beta})   \delta g^{\alpha\beta} - \partial_\lambda c^\lambda ( b_{\alpha\beta}   \delta g^{\alpha\beta})$. But $( b_{\alpha\beta}   \delta g^{\alpha\beta}) = \delta(b_ {\alpha\beta}  g^{\alpha\beta}) = 0$, because $b$ is traceless.  And you can reintroduce the Christoffel symbols and you find $- c^\lambda\nabla_\lambda (  b_{\alpha\beta})  \delta g^{\alpha\beta}$

Comment: @Trimok yes that seems to be the missing steps!

Comment: I don't see why $b_{\alpha\beta} \delta g^{\alpha\beta} = 0$. Isn't this only true of $\delta g^{\alpha\beta} \propto g^{\alpha\beta}$? Is it that we are only allowing those shifts of the metric that leave the trace of $b_{\alpha\beta}$ invariant? If so, why?

Comment: @Prahar : In your calculus of $\delta S_{gh}$, you use $\delta(b_{\alpha\beta}) = 0$. At the end of the calculus, we have a term proportionnal to $b_{\alpha\beta}~\delta g^{\alpha\beta}$. But $b_{\alpha\beta}~\delta g^{\alpha\beta} = \delta(b_{\alpha\beta}g^{\alpha\beta})$, because $\delta(b_{\alpha\beta}) = 0$. But $b_{\alpha\beta}g^{\alpha\beta} = 0$, because $b$ is traceless. So we can eliminate this term.

Comment: I do use $\delta b_{\alpha\beta} = 0$. While the trace of this quantity is originally zero. Are we varying the metric so that the trace of $b_{\alpha\beta}$ remains zero? My point is that just because $b_{\alpha\beta} g^{\alpha\beta}$ is zero, it doesn't mean that its variation is zero. Unless, the metric is varied to maintain the vanishing of the trace. Is that so?

Comment: @Eric : One remark (Ref :Polchinski, String Theory, Volume 1, page 91): Your action $S_g$ is a classical action, so we get a classical $T_{\alpha\beta}$. From a quantum point of view, we have to consider path integrals $Z(g) = \int dX~db~dc~exp(-S_X-S_g)$, and the energy-momentum tensor is the  infinitesimal variation of the path integral with respect to the metric. Practically, noting <...> an insertion of some operator into the path integral, we have  $\delta <...>  = \int d^2\sigma ~g^{\frac{1}{2}}(\sigma)\delta g^{ab}(\sigma) <T_{ab}(\sigma)...>$

Comment: @Prahar : In fact, I think there is maybe a problem of coherence in the question. The origin is the calculus of the path integral, in which appears the Faddeev-Popov determinant which is an integration on $b$ and $c$ : $\Delta_{FP}(\hat g) = \int db~dc ~exp(-S_g)$. During the calculus, appears the fact that $b$ is symmetric and traceless. But I wonder is all this has some sense outside path integrals procedure.

Comment: @Prahar : Yes, you are right : we have to suppose that each variation of $g_{\alpha\beta}$ is restricted to metrics preserving the traceless of $b$. I think that the argument should be found in the path integral procedure.

Comment: Two things - There is no sign mistake in my calculations. There is a sign from the integration by parts and another one from raising the indices on $\delta g_{\alpha\beta}$. Secondly, I am uneasy that only trace preserving variations of the metric are allowed. I believe that the right thing to say is that the metric variation is arbitrary, but $b_{\alpha\beta}$ also changes to maintain its tracelessness. I think this is the correct thing to say. Any comments?

Comment: Recall that the fields are Grasmann, so $ab = -ba$. And I think what you said is right.

Comment: @Prahar : I dont' get the point for the change of sign for "raising $\delta g_{\alpha\beta}$". I mean, isn't the above equality correct ? :  

$$\nabla_\lambda \left( b^{\alpha\beta} c^\lambda \right)  \delta g_{\alpha\beta} = \nabla_\lambda \left( b_{\alpha\beta} c^\lambda \right)  \delta g^{\alpha\beta}  $$

Comment: No. Note that $g^{\alpha\rho} g_{\rho\beta} = \delta^\alpha_\beta$. Thus $\delta \left( g^{\alpha\rho} g_{\rho\beta}  \right) = 0 \implies \delta g^{\alpha\rho} g_{\rho\beta} + g^{\alpha\rho} \delta g_{\rho\beta} = 0$. Thus $\delta g^{\alpha\beta}   = -  g^{\alpha\rho}  g^{\beta\sigma} \delta g_{\rho\sigma} $. So there is an extra minus sign.

Comment: @Prahar :   AAAArgh! Yes, of corse.

Answer (score 2):

The mismatch between Prahas EM tensor and the one in the OP is due to the fact that the $b_{\alpha\beta}$ field is traceless. To correctly take this constraint in to account, we can modify the action by introducing a fermionic Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$,
$$
S\to S + \frac{-i}{2\pi}\int d^2\sigma\sqrt{\hat{g}}\lambda h^{\alpha\beta}b_{\alpha\beta} \ .
$$
This action is on-shell equivalent to the original one, and has an unconstrained $b$-ghost which makes variations easier.

If we add the Lagrange multiplier part of the action to the analysis in Prahas answer, we obtain the EM tensor,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\delta S_{gh}  &= - \frac{i}{4\pi} \int d^2 \sigma  \sqrt{g} \left[ b_{\alpha\mu} \nabla_\beta c^\mu + b_{\beta\mu} \nabla_\alpha c^\mu   - g_{\alpha\beta}   b_{\rho\sigma} \nabla^\rho c^\sigma +   \nabla_\lambda \left( b_{\alpha\beta} c^\lambda \right)   + 2 \lambda b_{\alpha\beta}\right]  \delta  g^{\alpha\beta}   \ .
\end{split}
\end{equation}

By varying the action with respect to the $b$-ghost we can actually solve for the Lagrange multiplier, obtaining,
$$
\lambda = \frac{1}{2} \nabla_\alpha c^\alpha \ .
$$
Variation with respect to $\lambda$ of course constrains $b$ to be traceless.
Now when we substitute the on-shell value for the Lagrange multiplier we obtained the EM tensor in the OP!

This question and its answer are a decade old, but I thought to answer it anyway since the method of Lagrange multipliers is neat. Its worthwhile retroactively linking to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/541710/ghost-theory-energy-momentum-tensor-cft?rq=1) from three years ago, where the covariant derivation of the EM tensor is also presented, albeit with fewer steps (and I don't quite understand it).