# $bc$-system energy momentum tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, ghosts

I have a (maybe silly) question regarding the expression of the energy momentum tensor of the $bc$-system in equations $(2.5.11a)$ and $(2.5.11b)$ in Polchinski's String Theory, page 50. I know that this has already been discussed here: [$bc$ CFT Energy-momentum tensor from Noether's theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73737/), but I really cannot understand if the result I got is correct or if I am missing something.

Let us start from the transformations of the fields b and c: under a conformal transformation $z'=z'(z)$, a primary field transforms as in equation $(2.4.15)$. Since $z$ and $z'$ are just labels for points, one can switch their names, which leads to 
\begin{align}\nonumber
\mathcal{O}'(z,\bar z)&=\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial z'}\right)^{-h}\left(\frac{\partial \bar z}{\partial \bar z'}\right)^{-\tilde h}\mathcal{O}(z',\bar z'), \\ \nonumber
&=\left(\frac{\partial z'}{\partial z}\right)^{h}\left(\frac{\partial \bar z'}{\partial \bar z}\right)^{\tilde h}\mathcal{O}(z',\bar z').
\end{align}
Let us apply it for the $bc$-system case, where $(h_b=\lambda, \tilde h_b=0)$ and $(h_c=1-\lambda, \tilde h_c=0)$. Let us start from the b field and we will just state the result for c. If $z'=z+\epsilon v(z)$
\begin{align}\nonumber
b'(z)&=(1+\epsilon v(z))^\lambda b(z')\cong(1+\epsilon\lambda v(z))(b(z)+\partial b(z)\epsilon v(z))\cong b(z)+\epsilon \partial b(z) v(z)+\epsilon\lambda \partial v(z)b(z),
\end{align}
which implies
\begin{align}\nonumber
\delta b(z)=\epsilon\partial b(z) v(z)+\epsilon\lambda \partial v(z)b(z).
\end{align}
For the c field we have
\begin{align}\nonumber
\delta c(z)=\epsilon\partial c(z) v(z)+\epsilon(1-\lambda) \partial v(z)b(z).
\end{align}
Multiply now these transformation rules by a function $\rho(z,\bar z)$ and vary the action
\begin{align}\nonumber
\delta S&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int d^2z(\epsilon\rho\partial b v +\epsilon\rho\lambda\partial v b)\bar\partial c+b\bar\partial(\epsilon(1-\lambda)\rho\partial v c+\epsilon\rho\partial c v),\\ \nonumber
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int d^2z(\epsilon\rho\partial b v\bar\partial c+\underline{\epsilon\rho\lambda\partial v b\bar\partial c}+\epsilon(1-\lambda) b\bar\partial\rho\partial v c+\epsilon(1-\underline{\lambda})b\rho\partial v\bar\partial c+\epsilon b\bar\partial \rho\partial c v+\epsilon b\rho\bar\partial\partial c v), \\ \nonumber
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int d^2z(-\epsilon\partial\rho b v\bar\partial c-\underline{\epsilon\rho b \partial v\bar\partial c}-\underline{\epsilon\rho b v\partial \bar\partial c}+\epsilon(1-\lambda) b\bar\partial\rho\partial v c+\underline{\epsilon b\rho\partial v\bar\partial c}+\epsilon b\bar\partial \rho\partial c v+\underline{\epsilon b\rho\bar\partial\partial c v}), \\ \nonumber
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int d^2z(-\epsilon\partial\rho b v\bar\partial c-\epsilon(1-\lambda) \partial b\bar\partial\rho v c-\epsilon(1-\lambda) b\partial \bar\partial\rho v c-\epsilon(\underline{1}-\lambda) b\bar\partial\rho v \partial c+\underline{\epsilon b\bar\partial \rho\partial c v}), \\ \nonumber
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int d^2z \epsilon\bar\partial\rho(-(1-\lambda)\partial bc v+\lambda b\partial cv) -\epsilon\partial \rho b v\bar\partial c-\epsilon b\partial\bar\partial \rho(1-\lambda) vc\\ \nonumber
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int d^2z \epsilon\bar\partial\rho(-(1-\lambda)\partial bc v+\lambda b\partial cv) +\epsilon\partial \rho(\bar\partial b(1-\lambda)vc-\lambda b v \bar\partial c), 
\end{align}
where underlined terms cancel. Then from equation $(2.3.4)$ on Polchinski's book I would get 
\begin{align} \label{eq1}
T(z)=-(\partial b c-\lambda\partial(bc)),\\ \label{eq2}
\tilde T(z)=-(\bar\partial b c-\lambda\bar\partial(bc)).
\end{align}
The first equation is exactly minus what Polchinski gets. Why is that so?

The second equation should be zero as in $(2.5.11b)$: the only way I can explain this is that $\rho(z,\bar z)$ should instead depend only on $\bar z$ or that I should apply the equations of motion $\bar\partial b=\bar\partial c=0$, but I don't really see why.

Comment: i don’t understand why you think it’s ok to replace z and z’ but not O and O’. z and z’ are not just variables, they label the frames in which the various fields are defined, so O’ is defined in z’ frame and not z as you have written.

Comment: For what I understand z and z' are just names for points, right? It seems fair to me to decide to call them both in a different way.

Comment: i’m talking about the fact you wrote O’ instead of O in the transformation law. you can call the variables what you like but you have to be consistent. O’ is shorthand for $O^{(z’)}$, so when you change variables you need to take this into account

Comment: I did that because if you don't, when you compute the variations of the fields, you have to Taylor expand b' and c', instead of b and c. 
Isn't O' just the transformation of O? You could decide for example to evaluate O' in z, being it a function..
Could you then show me how to obtain the variation of the fields starting from (2.4.15) in Polchinski's book?

Comment: the variation of the fields is just as easy in this case, i.e. when (2.4.15) is the starting point (and when the variations are infinitesimal). the net result is the same as what you wrote but with the replacement $\epsilon\rightarrow -\epsilon$.

Comment: you state ' Isn't O' just the transformation of O? You could decide for example to evaluate O' in z, being it a function..' You can evaluate O' at any point you like, but it will always be at a point evaluated in the z' frame (not the z frame). these are tensor components, only primaries of vanishing weights are independent of frame.

Comment: Ok I see that $\epsilon\to -\epsilon$ should fix my first question. The only problem is how to obtain this result in a clean and right way starting from Polchinski's equation.
What confuses me is that one has $b'(z')=(1-\lambda\epsilon\partial v)b(z)$, but when I Taylor expand the LHS I get derivatives of b', not of b.

Comment: to leading order in $\epsilon$ you get b when you Taylor expand the left-hand side: $b'(z')=b'(z)+\epsilon v\partial b'(z)+\dots= b'(z)+\epsilon v\partial b(z)+\dots$ because the difference between $b'(z)$ and $b(z)$ is of order $\epsilon$.

Comment: In the last step you used again equation (2.4.15) to write b' in terms of b plus some $\epsilon$ terms right? Thank you very much for you patience and time, you have been of great help.
Do you have any suggestions for my last question?

Comment: You need to take into account (2.5.7) and (2.5.8), from which it follows that $\tilde{T}=0$.  You have to be careful with the normal ordering.  In general, for these free CFT's you can use the equations of motion inside the normal ordering (and when there are sources you need to be extra careful).  Also, derivatives commute with the normal ordering only locally and when the 2d curvature is zero, so when you set the curvature to zero you can assume normal ordering of a derivative of a quantity is the same as the derivative of the normal-ordered quantity.

Comment: .. oh and $\rho(z,\bar{z})$ is an arbitrary function of $z,\bar{z}$

Comment: Polchinski says that (2.5.7) satisfies the naive equations of motion, which means that $\bar\partial_1:b(z_1)c(z_2):$=0 for any $z_1$ and $z_2$ as a consequence of (2.5.6b) and (2.5.8).
After your suggestions now $\tilde T(\bar z)=:\bar\partial bc(z):-\lambda\bar\partial(:bc(z):)$. The first term vanishes for (2.5.6a) while the second vanishes as a consequence of $\bar\partial_1:b(z_1)c(z_2):$=0. Do you agree?

Comment: yes exactly, it vanishes by eom + normal ordering

Comment: I am really grateful to you!

Answer (score 0):

Because the transformation of the field is induced from the coordinate change, the function $\rho(z,\bar{z})$ might have been attached to
\begin{eqnarray}
z'=z-\rho(z,\bar{z})\epsilon v(z).
\end{eqnarray}
Then there would be additional term induced for $\delta b$ and $\delta c$,
and one can readily prove the undesirable term will be cancelled and $\tilde{T}(z)=0$.

Perhaps I am wrong and it is just a coincidence, so please point out my mistake.

Maybe I misunderstand the comments above, but if we concentrate on the form of the posted $\tilde{T}(z)$ above, it would be zero after normal ordering. Thus it means $\tilde{T}(z)=0$ in the sense of no other operator overlapping with it.